# How to install Pop Shell on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: extension

After upgrading Ubuntu desktop from 22.04 LTS, 22.10 and 23.04 in a row within half an hour, Pop Shell did not work. Can you please help teach me to reinstall Pop Shell ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop Shell is installed locally, so needs to be updated manually via the Git repositories. Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Ensure you have the latest version of the build environment installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install git node-typescript make
   ```
2. Clone the Git repository locally:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/pop-os/shell.git
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If you still have the original Git repository directory on your machine, change to that directory and update the codebase with a `git pull` command *from inside that directory*.</sup>
3. If not already in the `shell` directory (created by the `git clone` command), change to the directory:

   ```
   cd shell
   ```
4. Compile and install the Gnome extension:

   ```
   make local-install
   ```

Note that [there are some issues with Gnome 44](https://github.com/pop-os/shell/issues), which is the version that ships with Ubuntu Desktop 23.04. If you run into any problems, be sure to report bugs via the Issues tab on GitHub, as the developers of the extension may not visit this site very often.